# Incrementalloading Collection loads all data and doesn't release memory

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

My ListView only contains image controls which have a page of a pdf rendered onto them. I'm getting each page through a method which is called through a simple loop that goes as long as there a pages left. Since pdf's can be really large i would get a out of memory exception at some point due to the amount of pages rendered. I read about Ui and Data virtualizaiton and whilst UI virtualization seems to work my Data virtualization does not.
I read up on the Incrementalloading Collection and implemented the interface. In this collection i add every image i get from my method. I saw that the GetPagedItemsAsync method only gets called once at the start of the program.

```
public class IncrementalLoadingCollection :  IIncrementalSource<Image>
{      
    Rendering u;
    public IncrementalLoadingCollection()
    {
      
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Image>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        u = new Rendering();          
        var result = (from p in u.collection select p).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

        await Task.Delay(1000);
        
        return result;
    }       
}
```

Rendering is my class which performs the loading of the document and single pages.
I'll include a snippet of that below and i want to ask: **If my implementation of the interface is wrong or if there is a heavier mistake which disables the incremental loading of the data?**

in Rendering.cs:

in the constructor:

```
     public IncrementalLoadingCollection<IncrementalLoadingCollection, Image> collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<IncrementalLoadingCollection, Image>();
```

in the loadDocument function:

```
for (uint i = 0; i <= l_document.PageCount - 1; i++)
```

{

```
                    Image img = await LoadPage(l_document, i);                   
                    collection.Add(img);
                    g_rootPage.ListViewControl.ItemsSource = collection;
```

}

**EDIT1:**

I've put up a small example of my program on Github with the basic things that it should do excluding exception handling and such.

https://github.com/ShionLightwood/PDFDemo

Comment: Hello, `ListView.ItemsSource` only needs to be set once, and there is no need to repeat the setting in the loop. `IncrementalLoadingCollection` inherits from `ObservableCollection`, and when new items are added, the UI will be notified to change. But from your code, there should be no problem. Can you provide a minimum runnable demo so that I can reproduce this problem?

Comment: Really sorry for the late reply! I will update the question with a project that has the basic functionality of my program. I've put the Listview.ItemsSource in the loop because else it would take ages to see at least one page.

Comment: Not sure ... but using the async methods will only load the data "on the side" - you still go over _all_ pages and load _all_ pages into your collection. Where should the "lower memory consumption" come from? What purpose does `await Task.Delay(1000);` serve? Wouldnt it make more sense to say cache -2 ... +2 of the pages  based on "page 0" that you currently display? If you change this "page 0" you change the windows of cached images alongside it.  To lower reloads, you could also track the memory and say cache -10 ... +10 to facilitate scrolling without too much delay by reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your project, there may be some problems with the implementation of the `IIncrementalSource` interface.

`PdfDocument` can load pages according to the page index. So incremental loading means that we need to get the page after the current page index from `PdfDocument` when the page scrolls to the bottom, instead of loading all the pages in at the beginning, and then use `Task.Delay` to force a delay.

So my suggestion is to create a `PdfSource` class, its purpose is the same as the original `IncrementalLoadingCollection` (in project), used to handle incremental loading. But the difference is that the built-in variable is an instance of `PdfDocument`.

```cs
public class PdfSource : IIncrementalSource<BitmapImage>
{
    private PdfDocument _document;

    public PdfSource(PdfDocument doc)
    {
        _document = doc;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<BitmapImage>> GetPagedItemsAsync(int pageIndex, int pageSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        List<BitmapImage> result = new List<BitmapImage>();
        int count = 0;
        if (pageIndex < _document.PageCount)
        {
            for (int i = pageIndex; i < _document.PageCount; i++)
            {
                count++;
                if (count == pageSize)
                    break;
                var bitmap = await GetPageAsync((uint)i);
                if (bitmap != null)
                    result.Add(bitmap);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private async Task<BitmapImage> GetPageAsync(uint index)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        PdfPage pdfPage;
        PdfPageRenderOptions option = new PdfPageRenderOptions();
        option.DestinationHeight = 1200;
        option.DestinationWidth = 1000;
        using (IRandomAccessStream Imagestream = new MemoryStream().AsRandomAccessStream())
        {
            try
            {
                using (pdfPage = _document.GetPage(index))
                {
                    await pdfPage.RenderToStreamAsync(Imagestream, option);
                    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(Imagestream);
                    bitmap.DecodePixelHeight = 1200;
                    bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 1000;
                }
                return bitmap;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException ex)
            {
                Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog accessDenial = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(ex.Message);
                await accessDenial.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
        return default;
    }
}
```

There are two points that need to be explained:

1. Use `BitmapImage` to replace `Image`, because `Image` is a control, we can create it in `ListView.ItemTemplate`
2. Modify `option.DestinationHeight` to a suitable value, too large will affect the loading speed.

---

In the Rendering class, we also need to modify.

```cs
class Rendering
{
    private MainPage g_rootPage;       
    PdfDocument l_document;
    public IncrementalLoadingCollection<PdfSource, BitmapImage> collection;

    public Rendering()
    {
        g_rootPage = MainPage.Current;
    }

    public async Task LoadDocument(string source)
    {
        StorageFile l_file;
        l_file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(source);
        l_document = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(l_file);
        var pdfSource = new PdfSource(l_document);
        collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<PdfSource, BitmapImage>(pdfSource);
        g_rootPage.ListViewControl.ItemsSource = collection;
    }
}
```

And **MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<ListView ...>
    <!-- other code -->
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="BitmapImage">
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

After the modification is completed, incremental loading can run normally. That is, scroll to the bottom to load (you can add some loading instructions UI). After the loading is completed, the memory usage will drop significantly.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation ! I may have misunderstood the documentation then.